# What is the easiest and fastest way to import by bootstrap website onto concrete5 cms?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, concrete5

I have created a website using the latest version of bootstrap framework and am now at a stage where I need to make it CMS ready, so that my clients can edit/add/delete content on the site when required.

If somebody could give me some advice as to the best way to do it,  or point me in the right direction with a link to a tutorial i'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

The team at concrete5 have put out a [video explaining exactly how to do this](http://www.concrete5.org/documentation/developers/5.7/designing-for-concrete5/building-a-concrete5-theme/converting-an-html-template-to-a-concrete5-theme/) step by step. I suggest you watch it all the way through before beginning any steps.